# Protecting wooden plant pot from water damage

Tags: varnish, water-protection

I am building a large container for plants, made of pine. Considering that the inside will be in direct permanent contact with moist earth, what is an appropriate treatment to prevent wood deterioration? Would a heavy-duty varnish (e.g., spar varnish) be a good choice?

Comment: Using treated wood would certainly help prevent premature rotting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would a high-duty varnish (e.g., spar varnish) be a good choice?

In theory yes. In a thick enough coating (numerous full-strength coats) with no voids or pinholes, a varnish like this is essentially waterproof. It could last a long time in this setting although I don't know how the direct soil contact will affect it, to find that out you'd probably be best contacting one of the companies that make varnish and see what they have to say.

You'd get better performance from day one from using an epoxy coating of some kind. They're stronger, more waterproof but unfortunately tend to be quite a bit more expensive than varnish.

To get 100% waterproofing very simply just line with plastic! I would personally do this in addition to treating the interior, just to be on the safe side, but the plastic alone could provide complete protection to the wood if you're careful. Of course you do still need to concern yourself with the top edges and the exterior if you're using common 2x pine to build this, it is not at all a naturally rot-resistant species.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will check what I can find in the store. How does the epoxy behave when the wood expands and contracts?

Comment: I do favor the idea of designing the wooden pot to contain a plastic pot as a liner...

Comment: @Miguel Epoxy coatings are used on wood in a marine environment, so they should deal with expansion quite well (although there they tend to be used on all surfaces, encapsulating the wood). Using some sort of plastic lining gets my vote though, *much* cheaper and perfectly reliable if you do it right.

Comment: @Graphus Yes, I think I will try to use the plastic lining. Thanks again.

Comment: @Miguel Welcome!

Comment: One pinhole in a flexible plastic liner (stone in the compost?) would let water get at the whole pot. So it needs to be tough, maybe even rigid like an inner pot. A pinhole in a coating would lead to much more localised and slower damage.

Comment: I've had very good results simply lining wooden pots with a trash bag or two (despite the risk of pinholes). Easy to do and replace if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You could look into using cedar fence planks, which are usually readily available in nominal sizes in your home center garden department. Much more rot resistant than pine.