# Making a wood vase hold water

Tags: lathe

I want to make a vase on the lathe, and I also want it to hold water. I don;t know what finish to use because I don't know what would last. I know water on bare wood like that would cause warping or mold, something. What can I do to 'water-proof' a wood vase?

Also I do not have a specific wood that I am thinking of using.

Comment: I would think you'd want to use a heavy film finish, like a "bartop" finish or epoxy/CPES.  Also worth thinking about is finishing the inside differently than the outside if you don't like the "plastic" look of a heavy film.

Comment: Highly related (to the point of being a possible dupe): https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5333/what-is-a-good-finish-for-shot-glasses. Also, https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5279/waterproof-finishing-for-buffet and https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/4750/protecting-wooden-plant-pot-from-water-damage

Comment: @Graphus I don't mean to have duplicated any other question, I did not notcie them when I was looking. And thanks for the resources! Looking at the one answer you have wrote, oil-based polyurethane would work?

Comment: If you apply it thickly enough yes, it's waterproof. But no guarantees how long it'll hold up so if you want a long service life consider other options.